# How to stop In-order DFS traversal if value is found on a binary tree (not BST)

Tags: javascript, depth-first-search, traversal

I have the following function for in-order DFS traversal. I want the traversal to stop and return true if a matching value is found. But it is not working, it returns false even if the value is in the tree. What's wrong with this function?

```
inOrderDfs(node, value) {
    if (!node) {
      return;
    }
    
    if (node.left) this.inOrderDfs(node.left, value);
    if (node.value === value) return true;
    if (node.right) this.inOrderDfs(node.right, value);

    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning when those conditions are met, so it keeps going to the bottom and returns `false` :

```
inOrderDfs(node, value) {
    if (!node) {
      return;
    }
    
    if (node.left) return this.inOrderDfs(node.left, value);
    //             ^^^^^^
    if (node.value === value) return true;
    
    if (node.right) return this.inOrderDfs(node.right, value);
    //              ^^^^^^
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: I see but this is still returning false for values in the tree?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check for the value and then do the return:

```
inOrderDfs(node, value) {
    if (!node) {
       return;
    }
    
    if (node.left) return this.inOrderDfs(node.left, value);
   
    // Add this
    if (node.value === value) return true;
   
    if (node.right) return this.inOrderDfs(node.right, value);
}
```

However if it is a BST, then you can do:

```
inOrderDfs(node, value) {
    if (!node) {
       return;
    }
    // Add this check first
    if (node.value === value) return true;

    if (node.left && val < node.val) {
        return this.inOrderDfs(node.left, value);
    }
    else return this.inOrderDfs(node.right, value);
}
```

Comment: But this is no longer in-order, it becomes pre-order traversal. And still always returns false

Comment: @JAM You never mentioned inorder. Is it a BST?

Comment: It is a binary tree but not a BST

Comment: The updated answer would return `undefined` instead of false now for values that are in the tree